# Deleting to the begin of the line with d _

Tags: cut-copy-paste, cursor-motions

In Vim, <kbd>v</kbd><kbd>_</kbd> selects text from the current position to the actual begin of the line. Example:

```
Test test
   Test te|st
```

Now pressing <kbd>v</kbd><kbd>_</kbd> we get the selection:

```
Test test
   [Test te]st
```

From this I would expect, that <kbd>d</kbd><kbd>_</kbd>  deletes the same characters instand of selecting it. But it turns out, that <kbd>d</kbd><kbd>_</kbd> deleted the whole line, like <kbd>d</kbd><kbd>d</kbd> would.

My question is: why?

Comment: See [`:h _`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/motion.txt.html#_). In particular: *linewise*.

Comment: Thank you for the tip. It is clearly not a bug. But why is it done this way? Any logic behind it?

Comment: I think that the intended way to select to the start of the line is use `^` or `0` depending on what start of the line means.

Comment: Ah, ok. Unfortunately ^ isn't good accessible on a German keyboard :/

Comment: @BorisBrodski As @muru said, the reason is that `_` is a linewise motion, not characterwise. It selects entire lines. However, when you use a motion as a text object with an operator, you can temporarily force it to be characterwise by prefixing it with `v`. So, if you really wanted to delete from the cursor until the first non whitespace using the `_` motion, you could type `dv_`.

Comment: @BorisBrodski: About `^` which isn't easily accessible see [`:h 'langmap'`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#%27langmap%27). That can be useful.

Comment: Or @BorisBrodski you can `nnoremap ^` to a more accessible key.

Comment: @user9433424 , Cometsong and statox Thank you for the cool tips. Please, add those as answers, so I can upvote them!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [`:help linewise`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/motion.txt.html#linewise):

```
Generally, motions that move between lines affect lines
(are linewise), and motions that move within a line affect characters (are
characterwise).
```

`_` is a motion which can move between lines. For example, `2_` will move the cursor on the first non whitespace of the line below the current one. So, there's a good chance for `_` to affect whole lines when preceded by an operator, which is confirmed by `:help _`:

```
_  <underscore>     [count] - 1 lines downward, on the first non-blank
                    character linewise.
```

As explained in [`:help o_v`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/motion.txt.html#o_v), by typing `v` after an operator, you can still force the latter to use a linewise motion as a characterwise one instead:

```
v       When used after an operator, before the motion command: Force
        the operator to work characterwise, also when the motion is
        linewise.
```

So, if you wanted to delete from the cursor back to the first non whitespace on the line using the `_` motion, you could type `dv_`.